# Get unique values from one dataframe's column and use this to filter rows in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm looking to use one column in df1 as a filter on df2:

```
df1 = [('Client', ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D',]),
                    ('Num_Trades', ['1', '2', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1',])
      ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(df1)
display(df1)

    Client  Num_Trades
0   A       1
1   A       2
2   A       3
3   B       1
4   C       1
5   D       1
6   D       1
```

Now extract the uniquie clients from df1:

```
mask_array = df1.Client.unique()
mask_array = dataframe=pd.DataFrame(mask_array, columns=['Client']) 
# mask_list = df1['Client'].unique().tolist()
# mask_list = dataframe=pd.DataFrame(mask_list, columns=['Client']) 
display(mask_array)

    Client
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   D
```

Sample dataframe to filter on:

```
df2 = [('Client', ['A', 'B', 'A', 'Y',]),
('Product', ['GOVT', 'GOVT', 'GOVT', 'GOVT',]),
('currency_str', ['USD', 'GBP', 'USD', 'NZD',]),
('Amount', ['10', '20', '30', '40',]),
         ]
# create pandas df
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(df2)
display(df2)


        Client  Product currency_str    Amount
0       A       GOVT    USD             10
1       B       GOVT    GBP             20
2       A       GOVT    USD             30
3       Y       GOVT    NZD             40
```

The desired result is simply all rows summed on Amount where the client exists in df1:

```
Client  Product currency_str    Amount
A       GOVT    USD             40
B       GOVT    GBP             20
```

My code is producing 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed. I tried using array and list as well. So what needs to be done on the unique set of records so they can be used as a filter for df2?

```
d = [ 
        ('Amount', 'sum')     
    ] 

# aggregate 
mask = df2['Client'].str.contains(mask_list) 
df2 = df2[mask].groupby(['Client','Product','currency_str'])['Amount'].agg(d).reset_index()
display(df2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` with `|` for regex `OR` if need filter by substrings:

```
mask = df2['Client'].str.contains('|'.join(df1.Client.unique()))
```

Or use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) if want filter by values:

```
mask = df2['Client'].isin(df1.Client.unique())
```

---

```
df2['Amount'] = df2['Amount'].astype(int)
df2 = df2[mask].groupby(['Client','Product','currency_str'])['Amount'].agg(d).reset_index()
print(df2)
  Client Product currency_str  Amount
0      A    GOVT          USD      40
1      B    GOVT          GBP      20
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael! working. Quick question, so I can pass a list, array or datframe into mask? The issue was with the Amount being string?

Comment: @PeterLucas - it depends what need, but 1d arra, list of Series should working nice. DataFrame is problematic, need select one column (`Series`) or flatten values to Series or 1d array

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. I noticed the amount is actually a string so it needs to be converted ideally before groupby. If you can't convert here my solution:

Create a list of unique Clients of df1:

```
df1['Client'].unique()
```

> array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype=object)

Then use it to filter df2 on Client column

```
df2[
    df2['Client'].isin(df1['Client'].unique())
]
```

Now add the groupby and lambda to deal with string amounts:

```
df2[
    df2['Client'].isin(df1['Client'].unique())
].groupby(['Client','Product','currency_str'])['Amount'].apply(lambda x: sum([np.int(x) for x in x.values]))

Client  Product  currency_str
A       GOVT     USD             40
B       GOVT     GBP             20
Name: Amount, dtype: int64
```

NB:

```
apply(lambda x: sum([np.int(x) for x in x.values]))
```

does the following. Every value in column amount is converted to int via np.int and saved in a list. Then a sum is done on that list. Example: 
For Client A: amount '10' and '30' are returned by groupby but you can't sum strings. So convert individually and then apply sum().

Add:

```
.to_frame('Amount').reset_index()


    Client  Product     currency_str    Amount
0   A       GOVT        USD             40
1   B       GOVT        GBP             20
```

Comment: Agreed. Just be aware that .agg(d) doesn't do 'sum' on strings for me.